# PHP move_uploaded_file to NFS mount that is full

Tags: php, redhat, nfs

PHP 5.6 / Apache 2.4 / Redhat 6.7

Using PHP's [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) to try and save an uploaded file to an NFS mount that is 100% full, I would expect it to return false and throw an error. However, no error is thrown and the file is moved to the NFS mount, but the filesize is 0 bytes after being moved.

Has anyone else encountered this before? I'm curious as to why an error is not thrown and PHP thinks it has successfully moved the uploaded file, but in reality the files contents are not copied and it is 0 bytes in size.

Obviously, I can manually check the filesize of the tmp file before moving it, and then compare it against the filesize of the destination file after it is moved, but I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: Instead of checking tmp file size, can you check disk space before uploading?

Comment: @Andromelus yes, but what I'm concerned with is understanding why `move_uploaded_file` returns true, create a 0 byte file, and thinks it was successful, when it actually failed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the reason. I could not find anything about this specific topic on PHP website. Was just pointing out the workaround above because I think it would be  better than checking file size.

Comment: Agreed, it probably is a better work around. I also googled extensively before posting here and couldn't find anything, which is odd. If this was a known bug, there should be other people talking about it, which is why I'm wondering if I'm just missing something or have a bad configuration somewhere. I can't be the only one moving uploaded files to an NFS mount using PHP lol